# "github" and "git heroku" easy way to keep both

Tags: django, heroku, github

Until now I used svn as source control. At this time I have started a new project and it is stored on gitHub.

Issue is that Heroku and GitHub, both use git. First one to publish app and second one for version control.

My app schema is:

```
base-dir                                    <--github base
    some-text-files (Readme, ... )
    django-project-dir                      <--heroku base
        manage.py
        main-app-dir
           settings.py
        other-app-dirs
           views.py
           models.py
```

When I push to gitHub base-dir and all subfolders are pushed.

To Heroku only django-project-dir should be pushed.

Notice: I have tried to create a new git repository at django-project-dir level but git take it as a submodule and excluded from gitHub.

Because this is a new project I can easily change to another schema dirs.

My question:

**What is the easy way to coexist both Heroku and GitHub git configurations?**

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want your readme and other files in the root directory of your app?

Comment: In first moment I thinked that this kind of files (documentation for example) don't need to push to heroku. As I explain in answer I can change schema dir for a more easy coexistence.

Comment: In that case, just keep those files in the root of your project and add a second remote for GitHub.

Comment: ok, post as answer and I will accept it. Is the same solution than @kevinSylvestre but you have suggested it 4 minutes before.

Comment: Posted. Let me know if the answer needs any clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to move you readme and other files to your project root. Then just add GitHub as a separate remote (when you're in your project directory).

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPO
```

Then you can push to GitHub with `git push origin master`. You will have to do a forced push (the `-f` option) the first time assuming you're pushing what used to be the repo you used exclusively for Heroku.

You'll still be able to push to Heroku with `git push heroku master`.

Answer (score 3):

Your best option is probably to push the full repository to Heroku, but make sure Heroku ignores all files not required to run your application (see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler). Alternatively, consider creating two repositories (one for documentation and one for production code).

Comment: +1. This will simplify coexistence? I understand that .git/config file will store both configurations?

Answer (score 0):

You should have two remotes.

This is good and even desirable.

You have github and that's your remote code repository of record.

Then you have a current deployment via heroku and that is the 2nd remote.

Heroku is actually set up to use git as part of the system of pushing changes to your site on it.